# How can I correct PHP saying redirected too many times in local server?

Tags: php, redirect, localhost

I'm a newbie and got some issues I need help with them.
How can I correct PHP code which brings the "No connection" or "redirect too many times" error on local server?
I have the register.php file and the index.php and errors.php file.
This is the server.php code. I don't know what to do.

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$phone = "";
$email    = "";
$gender = "";
$errors = array();

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'work');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $phone = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['phone']);
  $email = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
  $gender = 
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
  $occupation = 

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...

  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array

  if (empty($username)) 
{ array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($phone)) 
{ array_push($errors, "Phone is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) 
{ array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
  array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");}
  if (empty($gender)) 
{ array_push($errors, "Gender is required"); }

  // first check the database to make sure 

  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or phone

  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE phone='$phone' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  
  if ($user['phone'] === $phone) {
      array_push($errors, "Phone No already used");
  }
 }
  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
  $query = "INSERT INTO register (username, phone, password, gender) 
      VALUES('$username', '$phone', '$password', '$gender')";
  mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header('location: index.php');
  }
// ...
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no visible error except that you are vulnerable to sql injections! Escaping is not enough! Use prepared statements. Please post the error

Comment: Your code above is not complete.... ie: `$occupation =` ?? How are people to help if the code provided is not the real code? Do NOT use `md5` to hash the user's password - it is not secure - use `password_hash` instead and also use a `prepared statement` and do away with the embedded variables and calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Your first 30 lines could be written in 6 with ternary operator.

Comment: Where are you being redirected to? Is it 301 or 302, open developer console to see. Is there mod_rewrite being used as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the reason that the code is giving you a warning about `"too many redirects"` is that `if (count($errors) == 0) {` is being called outwith any tests to see if there is suitable POSTed data and at that point the `$errors` array is empty - so if you happen to POST to the same page as the form you get an endless loop ( and thus too many redirects )

One solution is to move that portion of code that handles the `insert` to within the `IF` block as done here quickly.

You really, really should use a `Prepared Statement` and avoid `mysqli_real_escape_string` which can potentially change the data.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = "";
    $phone = "";
    $email    = "";
    $gender = "";
    $errors = array();

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'work');

    
    
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['phone']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
        $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
        $occupation = 


        if (empty($username)) { 
            array_push($errors, "Username is required"); 
        }
        if (empty($phone)) { 
            array_push($errors, "Phone is required"); 
        }
        if (empty($password_1)) { 
            array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
        }
        if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
            array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
        }
        if (empty($gender)) { 
            array_push($errors, "Gender is required"); 
        }


        $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE phone='$phone' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($user['phone'] === $phone) {
            array_push($errors, "Phone No already used");
        }
      
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
        
            $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO register (username, phone, password, gender) VALUES('$username', '$phone', '$password', '$gender')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }   
    }
?>
```

A very hastily modified version using `prepared statements` and altering slightly the logic ~ wholly untested so there may be bugs

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'work');
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['phone'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['password_1'],
        $_POST['password_2'],
        $_POST['gender']
    )){
        # the errors array only exists within the POST logic block
        # a standard GET request (ie: redirect ) will not enter this
        # block of code.
        
        $errors = array();
        
        
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $pwd1=$_POST['password_1'];
        $pwd2=$_POST['password_2'];
        
        
        if( empty($username) )$errors[]='username is required';
        if( empty($phone) )$errors[]='phone is required';
        if( empty($email) )$errors[]='email is required';
        if( empty($gender) )$errors[]='gender is required';
        if( empty($pwd1) )$errors[]='password 1 is required';
        if( empty($pwd1) )$errors[]='password 2 is required';
        
        if( $pwd1!==$pwd2 )$errors[]='Passwords do not match';

        
        # No errors at this stage - proceed to check phone number
        # to my mind this is odd - more usual to test an email than
        # a phone number but hey...
        
        if( empty( $errors ) ){
            
            # use a `Prepared Statement` ...
            $sql='select `phone` from `users` where `phone`=?';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$phone);
            $res=$stmt->execute();
            
            if( $res ){
                $stmt->bind_result( $cphone );
                if( empty( $cphone ) ){
                
                    $sql='INSERT INTO `register` ( `username`, `phone`, `password`, `gender` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
                    $hash=password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    
                    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$username,$phone,$hash,$gender);
                    
                    $res=$stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                    
                    if( $res ){
                    
                        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                        $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
                        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                        
                        exit( header('Location: index.php') );  
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            foreach( $errors as $error ){
                printf('<div>%s</div>',$error);
            }
        }
    }
    

?>
```

Comment: Yeah. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

can you add exit; after redirect

```
header('location: index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: This won't solve "too many redirects" issues.